# Múltiplo update em uma tabela de configuração

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber qual o melhor método para realizar update em uma tabela que tenho onde existem 3 colunas:

ID, Chave, Valor

Hoje estou fazendo assim:

```
UPDATE dbuf.dmds SET situacao = '0' WHERE id_demanda = '1';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '1' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'votos';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '4.5' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'tempo_etapa';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '2015-02-13 16:42' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'ult_mod';
```

Imaginem que isso está num concatenado em um único comando de texto, mas sei que o banco irá fazer 1 instrução por vez, então, gostaria de saber se tenho como fazer o procedimento 'em uma tacada só', para os casos de haver algum erro, não criar valores 'órfãos' na tabela.

Desde já, agradeço à todos!

Comment: Então @Juarez, a regra do negócio está certa, pois são 4 parâmetros que são propriedades da entidade dmds (demandas). A tabela foi construída dessa forma (id, chave, valor), pois no meio do caminho ela poderá assumir chaves de configuração diferentes (tempo_etapa pode deixar de existir no sistema, ou ser renomeada). Entendo que seja dificultoso mesmo... Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que irá ter que rodar os 4 updates separados mesmo, isso porque cada uma alteração em buscas diferentes (where), mas para não ter dados 'órfãos' pode usar transactions do mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Um exemplo de como ficaria é assim:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE dbuf.dmds SET situacao = '0' WHERE id_demanda = '1';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '1' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'votos';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '4.5' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'tempo_etapa';
UPDATE dbuf.flxs SET valor = '2015-02-13 16:42' WHERE id = '22' AND chave = 'ult_mod';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Boa Marcelo! Obrigado pela rápida resposta! Era isso mesmo que queria!